# Identify root folder in a file system in Python

Tags: python

I have a recursive method that traverses a file system structure and creates a dictionary from it. 
This is the code:

```
def path_to_dict(path):
    d = {'name': os.path.basename(path)}
    if os.path.isdir(path):        
        d['type'] = "directory"
        d['path'] = os.path.relpath(path).strip('..\\').replace('\\','/')
        d['children'] = [path_to_dict(os.path.join(path, x)) for x in os.listdir\
(path)]
    else:
        d['type'] = "file"
        d['path'] = os.path.relpath(path).strip('..\\').replace('\\','/')
        with open(path, 'r', encoding="utf-8", errors='ignore') as myfile:
            content = myfile.read().splitlines()
        d['content'] = content
```

At the moment, it checks if it is a folder then puts the keys `name`, `type`, `path` and `children` where `children` is an array which can contain further folders or files. If it is a file it has the keys `name`, `type`, `path` and `content`. 
After converting it to JSON, the final structure is like this.

```
{
    "name": "nw",
    "type": "directory",
    "path": "Parsing/nw",
    "children": [{
        "name": "New folder",
        "type": "directory",
        "path": "Parsing/nw/New folder",
        "children": [{
            "name": "abc",
            "type": "directory",
            "path": "Parsing/nw/New folder/abc",
            "children": [{
                "name": "text2.txt",
                "type": "file",
                "path": "Parsing/nw/New folder/abc/text2.txt",
                "content": ["abc", "def", "dfg"]
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "text2.txt",
            "type": "file",
            "path": "Parsing/nw/New folder/text2.txt",
            "content": ["abc", "def", "dfg"]
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "text1.txt",
        "type": "file",
        "path": "Parsing/nw/text1.txt",
        "content": ["aaa "]
    }, {
        "name": "text2.txt",
        "type": "file",
        "path": "Parsing/nw/text2.txt",
        "content": []
    }]

}
```

Now I want the script to always set the `type` in only the root folder to the value `root`. How can I do this?

Comment: You don't need to show us all the irrelevant code and output. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Does [PurePath.root](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.root) do what you want?

Comment: @PeterWood, thanks, I will keep it in mind in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something similar than the following implementation. The directories and files in root folder will contain the `"type": "root"` and the child elements won't contain this key-value pair.

```
def path_to_dict(path, child=False):
    d = {'name': os.path.basename(path)}
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        if not child:
            d['type'] = "root"
        d['path'] = os.path.relpath(path).strip('..\\').replace('\\','/')
        d['children'] = [path_to_dict(os.path.join(path, x), child=True) for x in os.listdir\
(path)]
    else:
        if not child:
            d['type'] = "root"
        d['path'] = os.path.relpath(path).strip('..\\').replace('\\','/')
        with open(path, 'r', encoding="utf-8", errors='ignore') as myfile:
            content = myfile.read().splitlines()
        d['content'] = content
```